# What is the meaning of “squirm out of it”?

Tags: meaning, sentence, sentence-meaning

I am reading Diary of Wimpy Kid (*Diary of a Wimpy Kid* - Book 1). But when I read to this page. I get stuck about like that

> I told Mom there was no way we were taking Manny with us, because we were going to hit 152 houses in three hours. And plus, we were going to be on Snake Road, which is way too dangerous for a little kid like Manny.
>   I should never have mentioned that last part, because the next thing I knew, Mom was telling Dad he had to go along with us to make sure we didn’t step foot outside our neighborhood. **Dad tried to squirm out of it**, but once Mom makes up her mind, there’s no way you can change it.

What is the meaning of "Dad tried to squirm out of it" in this situation?
**As my understanding. Dad doesn't want do that and he tries to find out some reason in order to not do that.**

Here are my research(https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/squirm+out) 
squirm + out of + something: *To disentangle oneself from some situation, duty, or responsibility, especially through sly, devious,*

Examples:
(i) You've squirmed your way out of doing the dishes for the last time!
(ii) Sally always finds some way to squirm out of any trouble she gets herself into

Thank you

Comment: Good research! You have correctly identified the meaning of the idiom, well done!

Comment: It looks like you've answered your own question.  Is there some part of what you've found that you don't understand?

Comment: Consider what was probably the original use of the term:  The parent grabs the child to get him to do something he does not want to do.  The child squirms (wiggles back and forth) until he escapes the grip of the parent and (temporarily) avoids what he found so onerous -- he "squirms out" of the situation.

Comment: @Scott. There are too much sentences like that , but I need research before I post here. Sorry because I am not a native speaker. I try to read that book to improve my vocabulary.

Comment: @HotLicks. Cloud you can explain more. As  I got it, Subject(he) is a son not the Dat

Comment: Once the idiom was established it began to be applied to situations other than the squirming child.  Thus a rich corporation can "squirm out of" a sticky legal situation (by pulling political strings).